# Python script frying my Pi

Tags: python-3.x, cpu, raspberry-pi3, cpu-usage, gpio

I'm trying to get an old rotary phone to work as a (menu) input-device. On a Raspberry Pi 3 I'm running the code below. It works, the script prints the number that has been dialed.
Problem is, that my Pi runs very hot, HTOP tells me the script takes 100% CPU usage. I need the while loop in order to detect every dial action (I do, do I?).

Besides: if I want to use this script as a base for a menu with 10 options, and every option gives (potentially) another 10 options, it shouldn't be this heavy on the CPU...

Any advice on the script and on a basic setup for such a menu would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Erik

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

c=0
last = 1

def count(pin):
    global c 
    c = c + 1

GPIO.add_event_detect(15, GPIO.BOTH)

while True:
    try:
        if GPIO.event_detected(15):
            current = GPIO.input(15)
            if(last != current):
                if(current == 0):
                    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.BOTH, callback=count, bouncetime=10)
                else:
                    GPIO.remove_event_detect(18)
                    number = int((c-1)/2)
                    print(number)
                    c = 0                 


                last = GPIO.input(15)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: Sleep the thread once in a while

Comment: You nailed it, thanks!